# Installing Active Directory Domain Services in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I need to install AD in a Windows Server 2012 machine. Are there any .Net classes that allow to do it, without using Powershell?

If I use powershell in C#:

```
command = "powershell.exe -Command \"& {Install-windowsfeature -name AD-Domain-Services –IncludeManagementTools}\""
procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I have the error:

> Install-windowsfeature : The term 'Install-windowsfeature' is not
>   recognized \nas the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program.

That is very strange because Install-windowsfeature is recognized inside Powershell.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: How are you launching that?  I just tested on a 2012 server, and the cmdlet is recognized in a 64-bit PS session, but not the x86 session.

Comment: I have just added the code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Install-Windowsfeature cmdlet is only available in a 64-bit ps session.
If you're launching from a 32-bit app or cmd window, launch powershell using the full path:

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

This should return 8 if you're in a 64-bit session:

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command {[intptr]::size}
```

Comment: I am launching from Visual Studio 2013, anyway I tried using the full path of Powershell like you said, but the problem is the same.

Comment: Did you run the [intptr]::size test?

Comment: Yes, I run from the DOS command prompt: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command {[intptr]::size}   but he replied:  [intptr]::size. If I run [intptr]::size in Powershell in the target machine, I get 8.

Comment: If I was diagnosing this, the next thing I'd do is run get-module -listavailable, and get-command install-windowsfeature in that session.  The ServerManager module should show up on the list of available modules.